# Select Dictionary's List with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i have a problem with c# dictionary. I want to retrieve List to use

```
ErrDict.Where(x => x.Key == kurumVKN).Select(x => x.Value) as List<ErrorModel>;
```

but it returns null.How can i get dictionary's list ?

```
Dictionary<string,List<ErrorModel> ErrDict = new Dictionary<string,List<ErrorModel>();
 if (ErrDict == null)
     {
       ErrDict = new Dictionary<string, List<ErrorModel>>(); 
     }

List<ErrorModel> listErrModel = ErrDict.Where(x => x.Key == kurumVKN).Select(x => x.Value) as List<ErrorModel>;
 if (listErrModel == null)
     {
        listErrModel=new List<ErrorModel>();
     }
        listErrModel.Add(errModel);
        ErrDict.Remove(kurumVKN);
        ErrDict.Add(kurumVKN, listErrModel);
```

Comment: the as operator will return null if the object cannot be cast to a List. As the answers indicate, ToList() will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
List<ErrorModel> listErrModel = ErrDict.Where(x => x.Key == kurumVKN)
                                       .SelectMany(x => x.Value)
                                       .ToList<ErrorModel>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `ToList` after `Select` and `SelectMany` to flatten your query that returns list of `List<ErrorModel>`. Try this :

```
var list = ErrDict.Where(x => x.Key == kurumVKN)
           .Select(x => x.Value)
           .SelectMany(x => x) // we add this to get only a single List<ErrorModel>
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
var result = ErrDict.Where(x => x.Key == kurumVKN).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

In order to avoid that Adam's pointed out correctly in his comment, you have to change the above to the following one:

```
 var result = ErrDict.Where(x => x.Key == kurumVKN).SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Note that this will return a `List<List<ErrorModel>>`, `SelectMany` seems to be desired for a single `List<ErrorModel>`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You should try

```
ErrDict.Where(x => x.Key == kurumVKN).SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList<ErrorModel>();
```

Comment: Note that this will return a `List<List<ErrorModel>>`, `SelectMany` seems to be desired for a single `List<ErrorModel>`.